# Scrolling to top of object within a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

Hi i'm having trouble scrolling to the top of an element within a scrollable div.

Basically Im trying to construct a trading ladder, with prices.
And based on the last traded price, I want the ladder to auto center itself.

As you'll see from the demo....
The first randomly generated price/scroll to works.
But subsequent scroll to seem to just randomly scroll all over the place.

[TRADING LADDER DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/zk2JL/2/)

Im not sure if its because of how Im selecting the element
Im basically putting a float into a data attribute and selecting the price that way

So in my table all price td's are

```
<td class='price' data-price=3.50>3.50</td>  etc etc....
```

Then im selecting it via jquery like so....

```
var pricediv = $(".price[data-price='" + price + "']");
```

It works for the very first randomly generated number.
But after that it stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: I solved this problem by just resetting the ScrollTop to 0 in the centering function.  This way it would calculate the offset from the top, everytime.  http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/zk2JL/4/

Comment: if you want to learn a little bit more about scrolling, I made a [post along with a demo](http://praveenlobo.com/techblog/how-to-scroll-elements-smoothly-in-javascript-jquery-without-plugins/) on my personal blog a while ago.

Comment: Just incase anyone ever comes upon this thread....here is the complete version, with the original problem solved.  http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/zk2JL/17/